# how to add new types to chart of accounts in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Am new to odoo ,

Am searching for a way to create/ add new types to the chart of account in odoo v 10 , when i create new chart of account only few options listed for the types

how can i do that ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Odoo reporting framework doesn't know about custom account types.  You have to be a VERY advanced user (with a VERY strong background in Accounting) to make custom account types work.

It is a much better practice to use the reporting framework to group or otherwise segregate standard account types if you really need to split things.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `menuitem and action` of `account.account.type` model, then you can create/edit records.

Try this code,

```xml
<record id="account_type_action_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">account.account.type</field>
  <field name="res_model">account.account.type</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
  <field name="help" type="html">
    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
      <!-- Add Text Here -->
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- More details about what a user can do -->
    </p>
  </field>
</record>

<menuitem id="menu_account_type" name="Account Type" parent="" action="account_type_action_form" sequence="1"/>
```